# Creating a new surface for a track layout with defined gradient of slope

Tags: slope

I am trying to establish a way of creating a new raster surface for a new track layout. I have a section of track, and I have a DTM. I want to give my track section a height value and a width. However I want to control the gradient at which the edge of my track then ties back in to the DTM. Ultimately I want to be able to create a whole new raster layer where I have a track layout at a particular elevation and width, and with a pre-defined slope from the edge of the track to the topographic ground. I want to then be able to use this raster layer with the cut and fill tool to be able to calculate groundwork volumes for the whole track layout. Does anyone have any ideas how I would create such a raster with the predefne slope values?

Comment: What software/version are you using? Also, define 'track' - is it a GPS track, or something else?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the resonse - the software is ArcMap 10.3. The 'track' is a path/road for vehicles. Thanks for any advice you can offer!